# Permutation code without repeating

Tags: java, permutation

I have a code with permutation and when I run this code, it returns multiple results with the same value.
I want to not return the same result, to break the repetition.

This is my code:

```
public class Teste {

    private static final char[] MP = new char[] {'i', 't', '@', 'r', 'm', 't', 'z', 'c', 'r', '.', 'c', 'a', 'a', 't', 't', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'i', '.', 'o'};

    private static final int[][] SWAPS = new int[][] {
        {2, 8, 18, 4, 0, 15, 1, 11, 3, 14, 20, 5, 19, 16, 13, 6, 12, 10, 17, 9, 7},
        {15, 8, 6, 2, 17, 14, 4, 9, 0, 5, 13, 7, 3, 19, 10, 18, 20, 11, 16, 12, 1},
        {0, 17, 20, 7, 6, 3, 14, 2, 18, 15, 19, 8, 16, 1, 5, 9, 13, 12, 11, 4, 10},
        {12, 11, 15, 14, 10, 4, 0, 19, 13, 17, 3, 9, 20, 6, 8, 16, 1, 7, 5, 18, 2}
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] str =  MP;
        int[][] out ;
        Teste p = new Teste() ;

        while (p.SWAPS != null) {
            out = p.SWAPS;

            for ( char e : MP ) {
                System.out.print(e + " - ") ;
            }
            System.out.println() ;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does it return, and what do you want it to return exactly?

Comment: And where is the permutation here? All you do is infinitely print the `MP` array...

Comment: I found the identical question [here with a better explanation](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/157236) (albeit in Portuguese).  Basically each index in SWAPS is an index to the next row in SWAPS to find the position of each character in MP.  For example, for the first character ('i'), start with SWAPS[0][0] -> 2, then SWAPS[1][2] -> 6, SWAPS[2][6] -> 14, finally SWAPS[3][14] = 8.  So the letter ('i') goes in position 8 in the final result.  Follow same pattern for each character in MP, and you get an e-mail address.

Comment: And what exactly are you expecting to happen. You can't just say "Hey, this is my code and is not working **as expected**". You have two outputs, the desired one and the one you get, just expose them both.

Comment: Also, if the fields are static, you can just call them without the use of an instance, so you could just call the arrays like this: `while (SWAPS != null)`, in which, by the way, will NEVER be null, since they are the source and final.

Comment: thanks mellamokb, that is want I want, to find the email =D

Comment: but @mellamokb This question is not answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not seem to use the SWAPS array at all.

Do you mean to use the SWAPS array in some fashion to decide which index from MP you want to print?

Also, you have a while loop that checks the value of p.SWAPS.  However this value never changes within the loop, so you'll get an infinite loop.

If you want to choose a random character from the MP array you can use the java.util.Random class.

I saw your clarification above where you specify how to find the position (8) for the first character in the MP array.  How do you find the position for the rest of the characters in the MP array.  If you start of at 0,0 every time, all of the characters will end up at the 8th index.

Comment: The `Random` should be used with care, since it may result in a non-balanced probability.

Comment: Thats the problem, I dont want that, I want to get out of the 0,0

Comment: to better answer, This is give me to an email, but I dont know how to do that

Comment: Your instructions don't have enough information on how to find the position for the rest of the characters in the MP array.  You've only given the information to find the position for the first character.